# File and folder access management and security (PHP/Apache)

Tags: php, apache, file, security, directory

I have a PHP website and I want to make sure that only logged in users can access certain data and that users can only access data the have clearance to access. I'm not really sure if this is a PHP or Apache issue. Let's say the folder "Images" exists on the server. If the user is not logged in and the browser requests can image from the folder, would a redirect to another page take care of it or do I need to involve Apache somehow to make sure that the user absolutely can't access the files unless there is a PHP session which identifies the user?

Comment: Depending on the type & size of files, an easy (&non-performant) way would to server all files via php. Move the folder to a non-apache-accesible folder & do e.g. `if($loggedin) { header('Content-type: image/jpeg'); echo file_get_contents('/private/file.jpg'); }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use php to verify the user and use an .htaccess file to deny any access to that directory  which isn't sent from php. However, if you use the .htaccess method, you'll have to get the image with php, it won't be accessible with html or javascript.
Put an .htaccess file in the image folder:

```
deny from all
```

With that written inside of the .htaccess file.

Then only php can access the files inside of the folder.

Comment: This seems to be the way to go. Now I just have to learn how to serve files using PHP.

Answer (score 0):

An entire directory can be made off-limits unless the browser has a certain cookie. Modify the `.htaccess` file in the wanted directory to include:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !CookieName=Value [NC]
RewriteRule .* http://www.example.com/members/login.php [L]
```

You have to change three things:

1. `CookieName` should have the name you want.
2. With `Value` behind `CookieName` you can require the cookie to have a specific value.
3. And of course the URL.

Now access will only be granted when the correct cookie is present in the browser. And of course only users that can log in should have this cookie. I assume you know how to make such a cookie? Tip: Let the cookie expire reasonably quick.

Comment: Does the value have to be static? Because if somebody's cookie is hijacked, then the hacker would have access to all the images. I'm not attempting to be negative. I'm just curious, because I didn't know you could do this and want to gauge its usability for myself.

Comment: Yes and no. The value is evidently static, unless of course, you write a new `.htaccess` file with a new value. You could, for instance, write a cron job that would change the value every day at 03:00 AM. But this is, with the right access and knowledge, always hackable, as you correctly assumed. If you need absolute protection use the method of passing everything through PHP.